# SSRS DateTime UTC format

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, format, ssrs-2008

Stored Procedure return datetime in utc like:
[image]

In SSRS report I formated date with mask "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss". But time was change
[image]

I think this happens becouse ssrs convert date from dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss PM(AM) format. How can I return time from sp normaly?

Comment: DateTime has no format, it's a binary value. SSRS uses the NumberFormat and *Culture* properties to format dates into strings. Instead of hard-coding the format you could set the Culture of the report/page/table/field to the one you want

Comment: What you see in SSMS isn't some built-in format. It's the way SSMS displays dates as text. It uses `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.fff` because it's unambiguous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `HH` for 24 hour format. `hh` is 12 hour format. So, your new format would be:

```
dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: There is another way. Set Language = ru-RU in report parameter